# XML parsers sometimes fail parsing large XML files on Android

Tags: android, xml

I'm parsing large XML files (~1-2M) in my application. Occasionally parser fails
when parsing some files.

Symptoms:

1. Sometimes the same file is parsed successfully, sometimes - not.
2. If parsing of a file fails it will take some time before the file can be parsed
   successfully again.
3. I use 2 types of XML parsers: SAX (XMLReader) and Pull (XMLPullParser),
   both of them fail near the same place in the file.
4. I use FileInputStream as the input source for parsers.
5. The same file compressed via zip and then opened via ZipFile.getInputStream 
   (almost) always parsed successfully.
6. I tryed to wrap FileInputStream with BufferedInputStream - nothing changed.
7. If parsing fails the next attempts to parse the file fail in the same place in the file.

I believe there can be two causes:

1. FileInputStream works incorrectly.
2. XML parsers work incorrectly with FileInputStream's (I heard both parsers
   implemented on the same base in Android).

Please help to fix the problem or advise a workaround.

Thanks.

Comment: in which way does it fail? any error logs (i.e. timeouts)?

Comment: It's parsers exceptions with lines:columns where XML-parsing error occurs.

Comment: Check your code for memory usage, you maybe reaching the 16M of heap size. This returns memory not heap: Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();

Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()  ;

Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() ;

Comment: Thanks for advice. I'll check memory usage with functions you provided. However according to Logcat memory does not exceed 6-7M. Ok, I'll check twice.

Answer (score 1):

This is the case if you experience the problem only sometimes. If the problem occurs each time you run the application the problem could be with XML.

In my case I believe it is device (I have Samsung I5700) or sdcard issue, because none of my application's users report same problem.

I'm going to reformat sdcard with android or try/buy another one.